# PHP finding the nth element in array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Php function to get the nth item in an array.

Here is something I do frequently.

```
$hr = array(' ','Mr.','Ms.','Mrs.','Dr.','Prof.','Rev.','Sir.',' ',' ');
$na = trim($hr[$rs['tbHR']] .' '. $rs['tbFN'] ." ".  $rs['tbLN']);
```

(this is just some example code don't take it literally) $rs = recordset of data where
$hr is an integer representing the persons honor designation.

What I would rather do is assign the array item on the fly with something like an nth function.  However, I'm not finding it in PHP. (I've looked for it)  Maybe there is a better way?  Any tips?

Here is what I'd like to do.

```
$na = trim(nth($rs['tbHR'],
array(' ','Mr.','Ms.','Mrs.','Dr.','Prof.','Rev.','Sir.','?','?')) ." ".
$rs['tbFN'] .' '. $rs['tbLN']);
```

Thus removing the need to create the variable $hr.  I don't want to create function either.

[EDIT]
Sorry folks, maybe my English is not so good.

Let say you have pets   array(' ', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'bird', 'snakes');
and sally has a cat.     sally['pet'] = 'cat';

But we don't want to store the word "cat" in our database.  Instead, we want to use numbers.   like sally['pet'] = 2;

In PHP you can:

```
$sally['pet'] = 2;
$pets = array(' ', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'bird', 'snakes');
echo "Sally's pet is a ". $pets[$sally['pet']] .".";
```

That is a lot of code just to convert a number to a string.  Plus, you've got a needless assignment of a variable $pets;

Is there a better way?

Comment: Your "here is what I would like to do" example seems to use `$hr` - I don't understand why you say "removing the need to create the variable `$hr`"? Did you mean `nth($rs['tbHR'],` instead of `nth($hr['tbHR'],`? And why `array array`? also a typo?

Comment: By the way - what is the objection to creating `$hr`? It is usually a good idea to have "string of titles" explicitly defined (in a part of the code where that makes sense) rather than hard-wiring it (possibly in more than one place) where you use it. Tends to make code more maintainable.

Comment: I want to assign a value from an array on the fly without creating a variable to hold the array just for the assignment.  Sorry for the typo.  I was just trying to show some example.   This is not actual code.  I use integers all the time that represent names of stuff.

Comment: What? You can get the nth item in an array simply by saying `$hr[2]` gets the third item.

Comment: This question lacks clarity.

Comment: I agree with you Floris about string of tiles but this is PHP not C++.   Philip Olson I'm not sure how I can be more clear.  Why mark my question as needing clarity?

Comment: I'm beginning to think everyone on this board is jerks.

Answer (score 1):

If your array has integers for its keys (which it does) then doing what you are already doing is correct, ie:

```
$hr[$rs['tbHR']];
```

If your array uses strings for its keys then something like `array_slice` would work:

```
$salutation = array_slice($hr, $rs['tbHR'], 1);
```